# bukkit - Waiting?

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

Recently I started developing a Bukkit Plugin and I need help with sleeping/waiting in my code. I'm kinda new to java so if you could explain it, I would appreciate. Here is my code:

```
@EventHandler
public void onTnt(PlayerInteractEntityEvent e) {
    Player clicker = e.getPlayer();
    Player rightclick = (Player) e.getRightClicked();
    rightclick.sendMessage(ChatColor.GRAY + "~" + ChatColor.DARK_PURPLE + "AN INSTAKILLER HAS YOU AS A TARGET! SNEAK NOW!");
    rightclick.sendMessage(ChatColor.GRAY + "~" + ChatColor.DARK_RED + "AN INSTAKILLER HAS YOU AS A TARGET! SNEAK NOW!");
    rightclick.sendMessage(ChatColor.GRAY + "~" + ChatColor.GOLD + "AN INSTAKILLER HAS YOU AS A TARGET! SNEAK NOW!");
    /* Then wait 3 sec. I've tried Thread.Sleep, wait() and sleep(), no sucess*/

    if (!(rightclick.isSneaking()))  {
        rightclick.sendMessage(ChatColor.GRAY + "~" + ChatColor.GOLD + "Bye bye.");
        rightclick.setHealth(0);

    }

}
```

Comment: I don't think a wait or sleep is the right idea here, make a new bukkitrunnable and schedule it to run in 3 seconds, so as to not sleep your plugin's thread

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While normally you'd use `Thread.sleep` for something like this, that would freeze the entire server, and events wouldn't be processed in that time (so even if the player stopped sneaking on their side, they'd still be sneaking from what the server sees).

What you need to do is use a `BukkitRunnable` (or alternatively a regular `Runnable` and `getServer().getScheduler().scheduleSyncDelayedTask`):

```
@EventHandler
public void onTnt(PlayerInteractEntityEvent e) {
    Player clicker = e.getPlayer();
    // Needs to be final to reference it later
    final Player rightclick = (Player) e.getRightClicked();
    rightclick.sendMessage(ChatColor.GRAY + "~" + ChatColor.DARK_PURPLE + "AN INSTAKILLER HAS YOU AS A TARGET! SNEAK NOW!");
    rightclick.sendMessage(ChatColor.GRAY + "~" + ChatColor.DARK_RED + "AN INSTAKILLER HAS YOU AS A TARGET! SNEAK NOW!");
    rightclick.sendMessage(ChatColor.GRAY + "~" + ChatColor.GOLD + "AN INSTAKILLER HAS YOU AS A TARGET! SNEAK NOW!");


    BukkitRunnable task = new BukkitRunnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (!(rightclick.isSneaking()))  {
                rightclick.sendMessage(ChatColor.GRAY + "~" + ChatColor.GOLD + "Bye bye.");
                rightclick.setHealth(0);
            }
        }
    };
    // Run the task on this plugin in 3 seconds (60 ticks)
    task.runTaskLater(this, 20 * 3);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am aware of the fact that this is an old question, yet I'd like to add something so that users who will be looking for a way to do may find this.

The simplest say to do this is creating a scheduled task:

```
Bukkit.getServer().getScheduler().scheduleSyncDelayedTask(this, new Runnable() {
// The stuff which should be accomplished after the timer runs out goes here.
// Example:
player.sendMessage("The time has ran out!");
}, time);
```

Now, let's get through the process of understanding what's going on here. Basically, se have created a delayed task (there are two types of scheduled tasks: delayed and repeating tasks). 
The first argument of the method above is `this`. This is supposed to be an instance of your main class (a subclass of org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin). This means that if the scheduled task is not in your main class, you'll need to replace `this` with an instance of it. The second argument is `new Runnable() { ... }` here we are actually creating the runnable. Whatever should be executed when the timer runs out, should go inside the curly braces. Lastly, the last parameter: this is the actual delay, measured in `TICKS`. This means, that if you wish to wait x seconds, you'll have to multiply x * 20, as a tick is equal 1/20 seconds, hence 5 seconds will be equal to 100 ticks.

If you know how to use lambdas, you can replace the anonymous class:

```
Bukkit.getServer().getScheduler().scheduleSyncDelayedTask(this, () -> player.sendMessage("The time has ran out!"), time);
```